# How can i make a method use the variables of other method?

Tags: python-3.x, methods

I need "method Two" use a variable of "method One" inside a test class, however i don't know how to do that.

I tried with self.a_value, One.a_value and self.One.a_value but none work.

```py
class test:

    def One(self):
        a_value=10
        return a_value

    def Two(self):
        b_value=self.One.a_value - 5
        return b_value
```

Expected method two output to be 5, but instead i get an attributeError or NameError

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'a_value'

NameError: name 'a_value' is not defined
```

Comment: `b_value = self.One() - 5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you return the value from `One`, you can just call that method directly. There might be more elegant approaches, but you could do something like the following:

```
class test:
    # ...

    def Two(self):
        b_value = self.One() - 5
        return b_value
```

If, on the other hand, you are *not* returning the value, you could assign it as `self.a_value` and then make sure that `One` executes before this is called:

```
class test:

    def One(self):
        self.a_value = 10

    def Two(self):
        self.One()  # make sure One is called
        b_value = self.a_value - 5  # use self.a_value
        return b_value
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python you can't access the local variables of a function or method. You must place `a_value` as an attribute of `self` instead of `self.One`.

In Two you access `self.One.a_value`, which would access an attribute `a_value` of the method-object `self.One` itself. This happens because in Python everything is an object and has a type - which includes methods.

So the following should work:

```
class Test:
    def One(self):
‎        self.a_value = 10
‎        return a_value

    def Two(self):
‎        b_value = self.a_value - 5
    ‎    return b_value
```

In this example the instance of `Test` will gain the attribute `a_value` after One has been called on the instance. After Two has been called on the instance there will be no attribute `b_value` as it is only a local variable during execution of the method.